# Who is being referred to in Exodus 1:20-21?

Tags: exodus, referent-identification

Exodus 1:20-21

> [20]So God was good to the midwives, and the people multiplied, and became very mighty.
>   [21]Because the midwives feared God, He established households for them.

In the above text it says he established household for them,but my question is who is being referred to here.

Did God establish the families of the midwives or because of the action of the midwives the Israelites increased in numbers?

How can we understand the above texts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed this verse is so unclear that there arose so many different interpretations throughout the years and it is almost impossible to say which one is correct and which one is not.

Literally the words "ויעש להם בתים" mean "and he made them houses". But the text doesn't indicate who made it and to whom it was made as the OP points out. Some have suggested that the verse is saying that Pharaoh locked up the midwives in designated houses so they shouldn't be able deliver more Hebrew babies. This interpretation is however hard to defend, since we would expect an explicit subject switch in verse 21 (Keelan's point in the comments). Alternatively, God hid them in houses from the Pharaoh who wantd them killed. See [Gill's exposition](http://biblehub.com/exodus/1-21.htm) for a list of interpretations. However, the anonymus translation you chose, prefers "households" over houses which is a little bit hard to defend since "בית" rarely refers to a "household" in the OT (however see 2 Samuel 7:11).

However, if we must go with your translation then i strongly disagree with Keelan that it refers to the children of Israel. This is very unusual language to describe the multiplication of the Israelites in numbers, and  "ויפרו" "וירבו" "וישרצו" "וירבו" (see verse 7 "but the Israelites were exceedingly fruitful; they multiplied greatly, increased in numbers and became so numerous that the land was filled with them") would be much more suitable to describe such an increase in numbers, and not "households" which is a most unusual term. **If we accept the OP's translation then it must refer to the midwives themselves,** that god established households for them as a reward for their refusal to follow Pharaoh's decree. Material wealth and prosperity may be included here in the בתים reward. (See bonus interpretations in the end)

As for the grammatical probelm, namely why there is a להם (them in masculine form) instead of a להן (them in feminine form)? there is much evidence that the OT uses the feminine and the masculine form of words interchangeably and rather liberally. See for example Genesis 31:9; Exodus 2:17 and there is many more. So *that in itself* would not be sufficient proof that the text here is not about the midwives.

**Bonus interpretations**: According to some, "בית" specifically refers to "hosehold of sons", so the meaning of this verse would be "and He established for them households of sons". In my view such an interpretation is more acceptable than the previous.

Another appealing interpretation i found in Gill's exposition is to "understand it of his building up the families of these midwives, increasing their number, especially their substance and wealth, making them and their households prosperous in all worldly good." The author himself prefers such a reading. Indeed this would ease the problem of why the bible uses such an unusual term to describe an increae in family size *only*.

See commentary of Rashi which might be of interest to you. According to Jewish tradition "Shifra and Puah" are identified with "Yocheved and Miriam" mother and sister of Moses. Accordingly Rashi explains, households here refers to the "household of priesthood" which eventually came out of them. Similarly we may add that "household" refers to an illustious lineage, meaning that god established for them illustrious or royal lineages (Egyptian or Israelite depending on the reading of verse 15).

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your last para, Rashi brings the opinion of Rav in Babylonian Talmud tractate Sota 11b on verse 15 and the opinion of Rav on verse 21. The purpose of this gloss is twofold, to explain why "them" is not "them" feminine in the MT when we would expect it to be from the context, and that the term "Hebrew midwives" should be interpreted as "the midwives who were Hebrews" rather than midwives who might or might not have been Hebrews, despite their patently Egyptian names, who delivered children for the Hebrew women. This is colorful folklore, but not  good elucidation in the modern sense.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim i am aware of sota. I didn't cite the other opinion of "households of kingship" because i didn't want to get involved in the  tradition of Miriam and David in regards to their relationship, since it is complicated and unnecessary. Furthermore this question is not about Jewish tradition or something of the sort, i merely pointed out an interesting reference which the OP is welcome to look up himself. Nothing deliberate here. As for the gramamtical problem i included in my answer and thanks for making me aware.

Comment: As for your point regarding the "midwives of the Hebrews", indeed it didn't occur to me that there is another way to read it. In any case, this is only Jewish folklore and was added as a bonus, it doesn't affect my answer in any way.

Comment: "Households" is an interpretation, which I too find odd. I would translate as "houses" and let the reader infer that it means that God lets the people prosper. There is no other masculine singular entity than God in the *textual* context, no other masculine plural entity than the people, and this provides a meaningful sentence. The masculine-feminine distinction degrades in later Hebrew under influence of Aramaic (which has final nun as masculine plural). It could be applied here, but I would be reluctant since the normal reading provides a meaningful sentence.

Comment: While they would not have my preference, I can see the point of most of the other suggestions you give (+1). However, I find the idea that Pharaoh made jails for the midwives very odd, because then you would expect an explicit subject switch in v. 21, and even if not you would not expect the subject switch in v. 22.

Comment: @Keelan good point, and i included them in my post.

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew is clear, "them" is a 3rd person masculine plural suffix to the preposition "for": להם. Since there is no other masculine plural group in the context, it must refer to "people" עם in v. 20. It is not uncommon to refer to this singular form with a plural, because it is a collective (the verb "became" in v. 20 is also a plural). The only masculine singular entity is YHWH, hence he must be the subject of ויעשׂ "to make". It would be odd to refer to עם first with a singular, then with a plural form.

The meaning fits in the overall tendency of the beginning of Exodus to put women in the spotlight (Meyers, *Exodus*, p. 42, also see pp. 40–41): through the midwives, the whole of Israel is benefited.

Comment: Please bring some support for the assertion in the last paragraph. It would be sufficient to list the number of significant events where women played a decisive role and the name of each woman or women in each event. The fact that "them" masc. is in the second clause of a verse that refers to the midwives (fem.) and begins with "because", results in most readers finding this verse very unclear. The classical commentators do somersaults to explain this away, with less that satisfactory results.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I added a reference. The other female characters mentioned there are Moses' sister, the Egyptian princess, the handmaids, the servant girl. The unclarity only exists in English which does not distinguish masculine and feminine "them". I don't see any issue in the Hebrew.

Comment: You can expand the theme of women in Exodus much more. The female characters are very strong. Yocheved who defies Pharaoh's ban, Miriam who both saves Moses as a baby and rebukes him as an adult regarding Zipporah and the Cushite woman, Pharaoh's daughter. Zipporah who herself circumcises Gershom thus saving him (Moses?). And of course, Shifra an Puah in our verse. The strong female characters are both Egyptian and Israelite. What is this subtext saying? You can expand on this much more.